# How to get Max(ID) from Student and Create in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

I am using one MVC example in which ID is incremental in database. To create the record it is like: But in my case ID in Student table is not incremental, I need to get MAX(ID) from Student table.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,LastName,FirstMidName,EnrollmentDate,CountryID,Account_Code")] Student student)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Students.Add(student);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(student);
}
```

I want to remove "ID" from my Include and want to get MAX(ID) from Student table through LINQ and save it to the table. Please help me thanks. Anybody help me to this please

Comment: A `ID` property suggests its a unique identifier so it should be an auto-incremented field (not something you enter). If you have multiple users, your implementation could result in duplicate `ID` values.

Comment: Then be prepared for you app to fail :)

Comment: Its not a field in old system, it gets Max(ID) from table like "SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 AS MaxID FROM STUDENT" and save this new ID into table when user press Save button

Comment: And multiple users making a save at the same time could result to duplicate ID's. Don't do it!

Comment: Yes true, I can make my ID auto incremental, but I have a field which is like a calculated field say AccountCode 1.1 or 1.2 and so on, I want to generated at back end (not entering by user) and save in table. Sorry I know this is silly question for MVC but I am new to it. so please dont mind